# How do I refer to a list item in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, web-component

I have a component that I'm giving a list to. I do loop through the list in the component to display another component, but each item in the list has an identical property that I want to display one level higher in the component.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Example code:

```
export const MyComponent = ({someText, someList}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{someText}</h1>
    <span>{someList[0].identicalProperty}</span>
    {someList.map((entity, i=0) =>
    <Entity
      identicalProperty={entity.identicalProperty}
      someProperty=[entity.otherPropery}
    />
  </div>
)
```

The idea being that I want to display "identicalProperty" once in the parent component but it is only available on each entity in someList. Is this possible?

*Edit:*

I forgot to mention, I am getting an error when I try this:
"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {someText, someList}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Comment: You have an open square bracket paired with a closing curly brace in the value of Entity's someProperty.  However I assume this is pseudo code you typed out and not your actual code?  Pulling the property from the first array element seems fine,  although you probably want to guard agains't an empty list with `someList && someList[0].identicalProperty`

Comment: @gvfordo Yes, that was just pseudo code. React does not like me trying to access a property of a list element directly like that for some reason. I've yet to figure out why though. :(

Comment: My guess is that "someText" is an object  rather than a string like you expect.  But there's no way to know without seeing more of the code.  React doesn't care if you access elements of an array (as long as you're not working with "children" which requires specific React methods),  so I think that's a red herring.  I would console.log() out variables,  or but debuggers in the render method,  to make sure the props/variables are as you expect.

Comment: Thank you, @gvfordo. I believe you are correct that "someList" is not what I'm expecting it to be. I think I need to make MyComponent into a class that extends Component and override the render method to expose "someList" so that I can use it like I'm trying to. I never would have realized that without your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not put

```
<span>{someList[0].identicalProperty}</span>
```

as part of the Entity component?

Comment: Because the data is identical for each item in the list, it will be redundant data and just wind up cluttering the interface. Note that an Entity component is created for each item in the list.